# How to get the AST of a regular expression string?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

How can I get the abstract syntax tree (AST) of a regular expression (in C++)?

For example,

```
 (XYZ)|(123)
```

should yield a tree of:

```
        |
      /   \
    .       .
   / \     / \
  .   Z   .   3    
 / \     / \   
X  Y     1 2
```

Is there a `boost::spirit` grammar to parse regular expression patterns? The `boost::regex` library should have it, but I didn't find it. Are there any other open-source tools available that would give me the abstract representation of a regex?

Answer (score 30):

I stumbled into this question again. And I decided to take a look at how hard it would actually be to write a parser for a significant subset of regular expression syntax with Boost Spirit.

So, as usual, I started out with pen and paper, and after a while had some draft rules in mind. Time to draw the analogous AST up:

```
namespace ast
{
    struct multiplicity 
    {
        unsigned minoccurs;
        boost::optional<unsigned> maxoccurs;
        bool greedy;

        multiplicity(unsigned minoccurs = 1, boost::optional<unsigned> maxoccurs = 1) 
            : minoccurs(minoccurs), maxoccurs(maxoccurs), greedy(true)
        { }

        bool unbounded() const { return !maxoccurs; }
        bool repeating() const { return !maxoccurs || *maxoccurs > 1; }
    };

    struct charset
    {
        bool negated;

        using range   = boost::tuple<char, char>; // from, till
        using element = boost::variant<char, range>;

        std::set<element> elements; 
        // TODO: single set for loose elements, simplify() method
    };

    struct start_of_match {};
    struct end_of_match {};
    struct any_char {};
    struct group;

    typedef boost::variant<   // unquantified expression
        start_of_match,
        end_of_match,
        any_char,
        charset,
        std::string,          // literal
        boost::recursive_wrapper<group> // sub expression
    > simple;

    struct atom               // quantified simple expression
    {
        simple       expr;
        multiplicity mult;
    };

    using sequence    = std::vector<atom>;
    using alternative = std::vector<sequence>;
    using regex       = boost::variant<atom, sequence, alternative>;

    struct group {
        alternative root;

        group() = default;
        group(alternative root) : root(std::move(root)) { }
    };
}
```

This is your typical AST (58 LoC) that works well with Spirit (due to integrating with boost via `variant` and `optional`, as well as having strategically chosen constructors).

The grammar ended up being only slightly longer:

```
template <typename It>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::alternative()>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(alternative)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        using phx::construct;
        using ast::multiplicity;

        alternative = sequence % '|';
        sequence    = *atom;

        simple      = 
                      (group)
                    | (charset)
                    | ('.' >> qi::attr(ast::any_char()))
                    | ('^' >> qi::attr(ast::start_of_match()))
                    | ('$' >> qi::attr(ast::end_of_match()))
                    // optimize literal tree nodes by grouping unquantified literal chars
                    | (as_string [ +(literal >> !char_("{?+*")) ])
                    | (as_string [ literal ]) // lone char/escape + explicit_quantifier
                    ;

        atom        = (simple >> quantifier); // quantifier may be implicit

        explicit_quantifier  =
                    // bounded ranges:
                      lit('?')                                   [ _val = construct<multiplicity>( 0, 1)   ]
                    | ('{'  >> uint_ >> '}' )                    [ _val = construct<multiplicity>(_1, _1)  ]
                    // repeating ranges can be marked non-greedy:
                    | (                                        
                          lit('+')                               [ _val = construct<multiplicity>( 1, boost::none) ]
                        | lit('*')                               [ _val = construct<multiplicity>( 0, boost::none) ]
                        | ('{'  >> uint_ >> ",}")                [ _val = construct<multiplicity>(_1, boost::none) ]
                        | ('{'  >> uint_ >> "," >> uint_ >> '}') [ _val = construct<multiplicity>(_1, _2)  ]
                        | ("{," >> uint_ >> '}' )                [ _val = construct<multiplicity>( 0, _1)  ]
                      ) >> -lit('?')       [ phx::bind(&multiplicity::greedy, _val) = false ]
                    ;

        quantifier = explicit_quantifier | attr(ast::multiplicity());

        charset     = '[' 
                   >> (lit('^') >> attr(true) | attr(false)) // negated
                   >> *(range | charset_el)
                    > ']'
                    ;

        range       = charset_el >> '-' >> charset_el;

        group       = '(' >> alternative >> ')';

        literal     = unescape | ~char_("\\+*?.^$|{()") ;

        unescape    = ('\\' > char_);

        // helper to optionally unescape waiting for raw ']'
        charset_el  = !lit(']') >> (unescape|char_);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, ast::alternative()>    alternative;
    qi::rule<It, ast::sequence()>       sequence;
    qi::rule<It, ast::atom()>           atom;
    qi::rule<It, ast::simple()>         simple;
    qi::rule<It, ast::multiplicity()>   explicit_quantifier, quantifier;
    qi::rule<It, ast::charset()>        charset;
    qi::rule<It, ast::charset::range()> range;
    qi::rule<It, ast::group()>          group;
    qi::rule<It, char()>                literal, unescape, charset_el;
};
```

Now, the real fun is to do something with the AST. Since you want to visualize the tree, I thought of generating DOT graph from the AST. So I did:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "digraph common {\n";

    for (std::string pattern: { 
            "abc?",
            "ab+c",
            "(ab)+c",
            "[^-a\\-f-z\"\\]aaaa-]?",
            "abc|d",
            "a?",
            ".*?(a|b){,9}?",
            "(XYZ)|(123)",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "// ================= " << pattern << " ========\n";
        ast::regex tree;
        if (doParse(pattern, tree))
        {
            check_roundtrip(tree, pattern);

            regex_todigraph printer(std::cout, pattern);
            boost::apply_visitor(printer, tree);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

This program results in the following graphs:

[image]

The self-edges depict repeats and the colour indicates whether the match is greedy (red) or non-greedy (blue). As you can see I've optimized the AST a bit for clarity, but (un)commenting the relevant lines will make the difference:

[image]

I think it wouldn't be too hard to tune. Hopefully it will serve as inspiration to someone.

Full code at this gist: https://gist.github.com/sehe/8678988

Comment: +1 for being masochist. I don't even have the gut to use regexes, let alone *write a parser* for them...

Comment: Wanted to thank you for this code - this was my core introduction to Boost.Spirit and now I'm rippin' away at my own project with it...

Comment: @DanNissenbaum That's nice to hear. Godspeed!

Answer (score 9):

I reckon that Boost Xpressive must be able to 'almost' do this out of the box.

> [xpressive is an advanced, object-oriented regular expression template library for C++. Regular expressions can be written as strings that are parsed at run-time, or as expression templates that are parsed at compile-time. Regular expressions can refer to each other and to themselves recursively, allowing you to build arbitrarily complicated grammars out of them.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/xpressive.html#boost_xpressive.preface)

I'll see whether I can confirm (with a small sample).

Other thoughts include using Boost Spirit with the generic utree facility to 'store' the AST. You'd have to reproduce a grammar (which is relatively simple for common subsets of Regex syntax), so it might mean more work.

### Progress Report 1

Looking at Xpressive, I made some inroads. I got some pretty pictures using DDD's great graphical data display. But not pretty enough.

Then I explored the 'code' side more: Xpressive is built upon Boost Proto. It uses Proto to *define* a DSEL that models regular expressions directly in C++ code. 
Proto generates the *expression tree* (generic AST, if you will) completely generically from C++ code (by overloading all possible operators). The library (Xpressive, in this case) then needs to define the semantics by *walking the tree* and e.g.

- building a domain specific expression tree
- annotating/decorating it with semantic information
- possibly taking semantic action directly (e.g. how Boost Spirit does semantic actions in Qi and Karma<sup>1</sup>)

As you can see, the sky is really the limit there, and things are looking disturbingly similar to compiler macros like in Boo, Nemerle, Lisp etc.

---

#### Visualizing Expression Trres

Now, Boost Proto expression trees can be ***generically visualized***:

Working from the example from [Expressive C++: Playing with Syntax](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/09/expressive-c-playing-with-syntax/#fnref:3) I slightly extended Xpressive's "Hello World" example to display the expression tree:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

using namespace boost::xpressive;

int main()
{
    std::string hello( "hello world!" );

    sregex rex = sregex::compile( "(\\w+) (\\w+)!" );

    // equivalent proto based expression
    rex = (s1= +_w) >> ' ' >> (s2= +_w) >> '!';
    boost::proto::display_expr( (s1= +_w) >> ' ' >> (s2= +_w) >> '!');

    smatch what;

    if( regex_match( hello, what, rex ) )
    {
        std::cout << what[0] << '\n'; // whole match
        std::cout << what[1] << '\n'; // first capture
        std::cout << what[2] << '\n'; // second capture
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of which is close to (note the [compiler ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific `typeid` names):

```
shift_right(
    shift_right(
        shift_right(
            assign(
                terminal(N5boost9xpressive6detail16mark_placeholderE)
              , unary_plus(
                    terminal(N5boost9xpressive6detail25posix_charset_placeholderE)
                )
            )
          , terminal( )
        )
      , assign(
            terminal(N5boost9xpressive6detail16mark_placeholderE)
          , unary_plus(
                terminal(N5boost9xpressive6detail25posix_charset_placeholderE)
            )
        )
    )
  , terminal(!)
)
hello world!
hello
world
```

> **DISCLAIMER** You should realize that this is not actually displaying the Regex AST, but rather the *generic expression tree* from Proto, so it is devoid of domain specific (Regex) information. I mention it because the difference is likely going to cause some more work (? unless I find a hook into Xpressive's compilation structures) for it to become truly useful for the original question.

#### That's it for now

I'll leave on that note, as it's lunch time and I'm picking up the kids, but this certainly grabbed my interest, so I intend to post more later!

---

### Conclusions / Progress Report 1.0000001

The bad news right away: it won't work.

Here's why. That disclaimer was right on the money. When weekend arrived, I had already been thinking things through a bit more and 'predicted' that the whole thing would break down right where I left it off: the AST is being based on the *proto expression tree* (not the regex *`matchable_ex`*).

This fact was quickly confirmed after some code inspection: after compilation, the proto expression tree isn't available anymore to be displayed. Let alone when the basic_regex was specified as a dynamic pattern in the first place (there never was a proto expression for it).

I had been *half* hoping that the matching had been implemented directly on the proto expression tree (using proto evalutation/evaluation contexts), but quickly confirmed out that this is not the case.

So, the main takeaway is:

- this is all not going to work for displaying any regex AST
- the best you can do with the above is visualize a *proto* expression, that you'll necessarily have to create directly in your code. That is a fancy way of just writing the AST manually in that same code...

Slightly less strict observations include

- Boost Proto and Boost Expressive are highly interesting libraries (I didn't mind going fishing in there). I have obviously learned a few important lessons about template meta-programming libraries, and these libraries in particular.
- It is hard to design a regex parser that builds a statically typed expression tree. In fact it is impossible in the general case - it would require the compiler to instantiate all possible expressions tree combinations to a certain depth. This would obviously not scale. You could get around that by introducing polymorphic composition and using polymorphic invocation, but this would remove the benefits of template metaprogramming (compile-time optimization for the statically instantiated types/specializations).
- Both Boost Regex and Boost Expressive will likely support some kind of regex AST internally (to support the matching evaluation) but

  - it hasn't been exposed/documented
  - there is no obvious display facility for that

<sub><sup>1</sup> Even Spirit Lex supports them, for that matter (but not by default)</sub>

Comment: added a small disclaimer to prevent any misinterpretations. This is work in progress. But it's showing real signs of potential, IMO

Comment: gah - Waited for the weekend to continue this task; Of course that quickly was the end of the road as well... In hind-sight, I should have seen that coming. I updated the answer with the conlusions. Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all you need to do is transform the raw AST with the Xpressive grammar to get the proper Xpressive AST -- look for calls to `proto::transform` in the Xpressive codebase. I'd help investigate over the weekend, but my video card at home is dead at the moment. :-[

Answer (score 2):

boost::regex seems to have a hand-written recursive-descent parser in basic_regex_parser.hpp. Even though it feels awfully like re-inventing the wheel, you are probably faster when writing up the grammar in boost::spirit yourself, especially with the multitude of regex formats around.

Comment: I've just [done just that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419351/85371). However, fair warning: I'm scratching the surface with the syntax variations. (I've tested the supported syntax quite well, though)