# How to input a mathematical expression from keyboard?

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple C program

```
int main()
{

    int n, maxn = 21;
    float SN, x;

    printf("input x:");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("input maxn:");
    scanf("%d", &maxn);

    for(n=0;n<=maxn;n++){
        SN = SN + pow(x,n);
        n = n + 1;
    }

    printf("%f", SN);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to make it versatile so the user can enter any expression to replace pow(x, n) with whatever  the user inputs from keyboard. How do I put an expression into the program?

Comment: there is tool that exactly does what you wnat it to. It's called *bc* and it is free software http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/ check the url out and have a look at the source how parsing mathematical expressions is done. if you are using windows you probably have to use cygwin to get a precompiled version of  it.

Comment: There is a theoretical possibility to do a similar thing as `eval` does by using a dynamically linked library. You can generate a simple code from the user string, compile it into a dynamic library and load into your program. It smells like hacking and you will need a compatible compiler on the machine where the code is executed. The question was put on hold otherwise I'd post a demo code ...

Answer (score 10):

C and C++ don't offer you this feature already implemented because there is a clear cut between the compile time (when expressions are analyzed syntactically) and run time (when they're evaluated).

Implementing a parser and compiler/evaluator for expression is a good exercise but it's not trivial and would probably require a lot more experience than you have at this moment (given the question you asked).

The easiest to understand approach to this problem is in my opinion a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) but for just the four operations, numbers and variables I'd guess it would require a hundred or so lines of code.

[yacc and bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) are tools that were designed to generate automatically parsing/evaluation code from a definition of a grammar. I personally prefer to hand-write parsers because of the finer control you get (especially on error handling or when the syntactic and semantic level interact, but that's me and I'm also a bad case of [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)).

Higher level languages like Python or Javascript instead offer you this feature already implemented as `eval`.

Comment: Is there an existing library that can help me?

Comment: @Euphe: the historical tools for this problem are yacc/bison, see edited answer for some links to descriptions.

Comment: have you checked what you can do with boost spirit... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419351/1000282

Comment: offloading `boost::spirit` to somebody who just started programming is way overkill.

Comment: @Alex: `boost.spirit` is a bad idea for **anyone**. In my opinion is an amazing example of how far intelligent people can walk in a nonsense direction without realizing it.