# Parser for regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, dfa

I've been studying basics recently and as a practice I've decided to implement a DFA in the context of C++. So basically it's regular expressions. It works well when I construct the tree from scratch however I'm not sure how to deal with regular expressions.

What I mean is if I have a regex, for example `(test)*` I have to convert it into a DFA. The problem is that in order to do that I have to parse the regular expression. This seems to be a vicious circle (it's even worse because I actually need a bracket-aware parser, regular expressions won't work here).

So how to deal with it? I completely understand that we have tools now to do that (e.g. Flex & Bison) but these tools are based on regular expressions (well, at least tokenizers are). So what happened at the begining? How to write a regex parser from scratch? Any reference to a book/article appreciated.

Comment: Before there were parser generators, people programmed it by hand. Just like they wrote assembly code before there were high level language compilers.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that. However I'm not sure how would one write a parser without regular expressions? Perhaps I'm just overcomplicating things, I'm just trying to learn stuff.

Comment: You could try writing a parser in boost spirit - I doubt you'd need to use regular expressions....

Comment: You write lots of `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: If you have never had to write a language parser without benefit of a regex engine to handle your DFA's consider yourself lucky (and I'm sorely disappointed in the quality of whatever algorithm language and compiler design course you took). You haven't really *lived* until you code a tokenizer to comply with your already-hand-crafted DFA *by-hand*. It is its own world of "special".

Comment: @WhozCraig I've never said I'm writing a language parser. Also I didn't take *any* course in programming (I'm purely self taught). I'll try to write it with lots of `if` and `switch` statements as suggested by Barmar. :)

Comment: @TonyD Cue my simple **[Regex Parser written with Boost Spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657130/how-to-get-the-ast-of-a-regular-expression-string/21419351#21419351)**? :)

Comment: @sehe you're an animal, sir. (and if anyone doesn't believe that, check out his avatar =)

Comment: @WhozCraig, have you ever heard of the lexerless parsing? Tokenisers are so last century.

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinators - there is a huge world outside of the narrow dragon book way of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once wrote my own version of Flex, which generated a set of classes instead of the whole program. Firstly, I had to parse the regular expressions by hand, but when I finally wrote it, I replaced the regular expression parsing mechanism with one generated by the program itself.

Manual parsing of the regular expression is actually quite simple. Firstly, you have to specify the result you want to achieve. For example in my case:

```
[abc]+test
```

Is being interpreted as:

```
[abc]@[abc]*@[t]@[e]@[s]@[t]
```

Which are actually equivalent (@ is an artificially added concatenation operator).

Then you have to create a set of rules, eg.

```
'[' spotted:
    - (optionally) expect '^' character;
    - repeat:
        - expect a non-special character;
            - If it is not last character and is succeeded by '-', expect another character
    - until `]` is spotted
    - Return a character set
'(' spotted:
    - Return a block-begin
')' spotted:
    - Return a block-end
'*' spotted:
    - Return a star-operator
'+' spotted:
    - Return a plus-operator
'.' spotted:
    - Return a whole character set
Any other char spotted:
    - Return a character set consisting of this single character
```

Algorithm written like this will give you a tokenizer - routine, which breaks elements into logical tokens. Then you'll have to process them into an expression tree and that may be solved by implementing a [Reverse Polish Notation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

You can check my parser generator [here](http://www.spook.freshsite.pl/Temporary/SpkParserGenerator.zip), though it generates a Delphi code. Unfortunately, readme is in Polish, but there are a few examples inside. Try for instance:

```
Number=[0-9]+
Operator=[\+\-\*/]
```

And

```
SpkParserGenerator -i myfile.regex -mc -sg
```

By the way, you can generate a parser for yourself and then simply translate it from Delphi to C++, it's actually quite simple even if you don't know Delphi well.

This is a set of rules I used to generate parser for the parser generator:

```
SetRange=\{([0-9]*,[0-9]+)|([0-9]+,[0-9]*)|([0-9]+)\}
Star=\*
Plus=\+
QMark=\?
CharRange=\[\^?((\\.)|(\#[0-9]{3})|([^\\\#\]]))+\]
AnyChar=\.
EscapedChar=\\.
AsciiChar=\#[0-9]{3}
Char=[^\[\]\{\}\.\(\)\#\*\+\?\|\\]
OpenParenthesis=\(
CloseParenthesis=\)
Alternative=\|
```

Comment: I'm not, guess I'll have to Reverse the Polish Notation first :D